# Editing attribute data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, filter

I have a large address file with the address (as an example)

Adilsvej 16,4 tv  ,DK-2000,Frederiksberg

I need to remove the DK- from the 6000 plus rows.

Can someone advice?

Comment: `regexp_replace()` is the expression to use.

Comment: or simply `replace(field,',DK-',',')` if it is always the same text to remove

Comment: The expressions above can be executed using the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator)